# Convert string dd/mm/yy to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format, type-conversion

I need to convert a string format `dd/mm/yy` to a `datetime`.

I tried with:

```
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("es-es"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out d))
    return d;
```

Comment: What about this didn't work?  What is the value of dateStr?

Comment: The problem is that i have dd/mm/yy format and Not dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex That's for javascript and the OP is looking for a C# answer.

Comment: If the format is "dd/MM/yy" then why don't you use that instead of "dd/MM/yyyy"?  The format you specify to `DateTime.TryParseExact` has to exactly match the format of the string you are parsing.  Also note there is an overload that will take an array of formats if you want it to try parsing with a 4 digit year first and then a 2 digit year.

Comment: There is a reason the method is named TryParse**Exact**. The format specified has to **exactly** match the input. If you want to parse a string containing only two digits for the year, use `"dd/MM/yy"`, not `yyyy`.

Comment: @juharr You're right. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code seems ok, but also you can convert a string into datetime like below

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("11/02/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return d;
```

if you have string as `dd/MM/yy` format and need to convert it as `dd/MM/yyyy` fomat datetime then you can do like this

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact("11/02/16", "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
return d
```

Comment: The problem is that i have dd/mm/yy format and Not dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: so you have string as dd/MM/yy format and you want it  dd/MM/yyyy format datetime  ?

Answer (score -1):

```
string dateBirth = ddlDay.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + ddlYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.

Comment: People can convert the string value to exact format.

Comment: Please add such an explanation to your answer by editing it.